# use dictionary_1's keys to search for a match in dictionary_2's values

Tags: python-2.7

let's say I have 2 dictionaries in python. in the first dictionary I have a key 'Obama' and I want to know if there's a key like that found in the other dictionary's "values"(not keys). thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work

```
list1 = [ key for key in mydict1.keys() if key in mydict2.itervalues() ]
```